# Trying to access our FTP server. Getting "Killed 9." How do I resolve this?

Tags: command-line, error, ftp

I just tried to access our FTP server via the command-line FTP client on my new M2 Mini.

And it gives an immediate "Killed 9" message.

On my 2017 iMac (Catalina):

(Note that the ftp server domain name "has been changed to protect the innocent")

```
ftp xxx.com
Connected to xxx.com.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (xxx.com:foo): yyy
331 Please specify the password.
Password: 
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

On an AS/400 in the cloud:

```
  Connecting to host XXX.COM at address 35.174.190.169 using port 21.
  220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)                                                      
> yyy                                                                
  331 Please specify the password.                                        
  230 Login successful.                                                   
  UNIX Type: L8
```

On my M2 Mini:

```
ftp xxx.com
Killed: 9
```

On my M2 Mini, trying to connect to an FTP server on the same LAN, only one desk over, server name in my host table, that also works just fine from my 2017 iMac, and from a couple of AS/400s in the same room:

```
ftp europa
Killed: 9
```

The ftp *and telnet* commands *both* fail with `Killed 9` on the Mini, *even if I don't specify a server.* And that doesn't happen on the 2017 iMac.

I'm pretty sure I had to stick both the command line FTP and the command line Telnet back onto the iMac when I updated it to Catalina.

Comment: What did you enter to access your FTP server?

Comment: “Killed 9” means the *server* killed the process with a signal “9”.  There’s no error, it’s just the process handling the FTP daemon wanted the FTP process killed at that moment. Unfortunately, you need to bring this up with the server admin to see what’s going on as it’s not client related

Comment: "Thinkr": I entered "FTP xxx.com" on a command line.

Comment: "Allan": I *am* the server admin. And there are no access restrictions on the FTP server. Not five minutes after the failure, I successfully connected to it from two different AS/400s, in two different physical locations and IP addresses, and from my 2017 iMac on the same desk (and on the same LAN, at the same public IP address) as the new Mini, without any problems at all, but the Mini continues to exhibit the same behavior: "Killed 9" without so much as a prompt for user ID.

Comment: And note that "xxx.com" is of course a case of "the names have been changed to protect the innocent."

Comment: And I get the same "Killed 9" with a different FTP server, on the same LAN, that continues to work just fine with my 2017 iMac.

Comment: First, use "@user" when replying we won't get notified otherwise.  "Killed 9" is a server thing.  FTP is ancient (as time passes in IT) and I don't believe it's included with macOS anymore (could be mistaken).  Are you using a 3rd party FTP client?

Comment: @Allan: Now that I think about it, I think I might have had to *put* the command-line FTP and Telnet clients on the 2017 iMac after updating it to Catalina: they're both in /usr/local/bin

Comment: @Allan I just learned that it fails with "Killed 9" even if I don't specify a server, so it can't be coming from the server.

Comment: Okay, thanks for having added this additional info. Nice edit! :)

Comment: ok...that's good to know.  It might be a *permissions* issue with FTP.  Did you allow disk access for FTP (Accessibility) and are you running any type of firewall?

Comment: Killed 9 is a local issue. Are you running an Intel binary on ARM without Rosetta installed?

Comment: Good catch @nohillside!  I keep forgetting about this architecture change.

Comment: @nohillside: It must have Rosetta; it runs a lot of the other stuff that Migration Assistant brought over from the iMac. At any rate, remembering what I'd had to do on the iMac prompted me to additional Google searches that took me to the OS X Daily pages referenced in my answer.

Comment: @Allan: Yes, with the change from Intel to Apple Silicon/ARM, the Macintosh has now had twice as many changes of fundamental processor architecture than the IBM AS/400 (which went from a CISC component CPU to an enhanced PowerPC, and did it, so long as you weren't employing undocumented hacks, *seamlessly*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, on OS X Daily. It's a slightly different FTP client (e.g., it doesn't accept "exit" as a synonym for "quit"), but it solves the overriding problem of no command-line FTP or Telnet.

First, install Homebrew:
https://osxdaily.com/2018/03/07/how-install-homebrew-mac-os/

It will most likely finish (at least it did for me) by giving you a pair of rather complicated commands to put Homebrew in your path.

Second, install the "inetutils" homebrew package:
https://osxdaily.com/2018/08/07/get-install-ftp-mac-os/

This will give you command-line FTP, command-line Telnet, as well as a few I've never used (or even heard of), dnsdomainname, rcp, rexec, rlogin, and rsh.

If after doing this, you find yourself getting

```
500 Illegal PORT command.
500 Unknown command.
425 Use PORT or PASV first.
```

then you've found another difference between this FTP client and the one that used to be included in the OS, namely, it doesn't have passive mode enabled by default. Either enter the `pass` (not "pasv") command within ftp, or use the `-p` switch on the `ftp` command, for example,

```
ftp -p foo.com
```

or if you use it a lot, put `alias ftp='ftp -p'` in your .bash_profile or .bashrc file.

Comment: i rolled back your edit, don‘t think it‘s relevant for the problem stated in the question so it will rather distract from the actual answer.

Comment: Uh, anybody else who follows the answer and installs the Homebrew and inetutils is probably going to run into the same problem I did.